# Why can't element objects be selected by tag name just like document.body?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

It might be a stupid question to some but I am curious to know, why `document.body.p` doesn't work but `document.body` works and instead of using `document.body.getElementById('mypara')`.

In `document.body` we reference body by its `tagName: body` so why `document.body.p` doesn't work.

Thanks

Comment: I don't see the point of this question since javascript offers the use of `document.getElementsByTagName('p')` which will return a node list, the return of `document.body.p` would also have to offer the same result in case of multiple paragraph elements being found.

Comment: One reason is that `document.body` could have multiple paragraph elements in it.

Comment: You have only one body element in a page, like head or title. It's more obvious to have these elements has properties instead of p or div...

Comment: @JonathanAnctil  thre is only one html element but there is no document.html. how do u explain that?

Comment: @appu what about document.documentElement?

Answer (score 5):

Because it is guaranteed that there is only one body in a document(at least ideally). When you do `document.body.p` there is no guarantee that there is only one p element in document. Which p element should return if there are multiple p's ? No right.

---

*Question from comment :*

but then you also have only one html element (ideally) and that but there is no document.html. right??

Yeah there is.

```
Document.documentElement
```

> Returns the Element that is a direct child of the document. For HTML documents, this is normally the  element.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Document

Note that `documentElement` is read only.

Comment: but then you also have only one `html` element (ideally) and that but there is no `document.html`. right??

Comment: @appu Added in my answer.

Comment: I think you are missing the point of my question. I am referring to tagnames not API's (`getElementsByTagName`) or property names (`documentElement`) generally used to access DOM elements. `documentElement` is not the tag name of `<html></html>` but `html`. So if there is `document.body` then why there isn't `document.html` since there's only one of each.

Comment: @appu You understood them wrong. It is not accessing by tag name. Those are the property added to the document object. Choosen the apted name. Doesn't mean that it is exact tag name

Comment: @appu - to back this up, note that `document.body` does not only return the  body element of the document. In web pages that have a frameset element instead of a body element, document.body will return that frameset element.

Answer (score 0):

document.body returns a reference to the body element of a webpage.  That element may be a parent to other elements, known as children.  In this case, the first child is the paragraph element which the code reads by applying an index of zero to children, as follows:

```js
console.log(document.body.children[0]);
console.log(document.body.children[0].textContent);
```

```html
<body>
<p>text</p>
```

If you wish to read the contents of the paragraph you just need to refer to its "textContent" or "innerText".

Answer (score 0):

Because `document` is an [HTMLDocument](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLDocument) object with the properties listed [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document), and one of those properties is `body`, which is an instance of [HTMLElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement). You can try this in your browser's console:

- `document instanceof HTMLElement` will return `false`.
- `document instanceof HTMLDocument` will return `true`.
- `document.body instanceof HTMLElement` will return `true`.

So now we know that `document` and `document.body` are different types of objects. You can browse Mozilla's documentation at the links above to see the properties and methods available on each type of object. For example, [getElementById](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById) is only available on `document`, and [getElementsByTagName](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getElementsByTagName) is available on any [Element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element) object, such as `body` (the `Element` interface is the parent of `HTMLElement`, and so `HTMLElement` will also have methods available from `Element`).

If all tagnames were allowed to be accessed like a property, such as `document.body.p`, one problem that would arise is naming conflicts. `document.body.style` returns a [CSSStyleDeclaration](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSSStyleDeclaration), but if `style` were treated as a tagname as you propose then it would have to return an [HTMLCollection](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection) of `<style>` elements. (Although technically having `<style>` elements in the body is invalid, the browser will still parse it.)